# How to find linear trend in R?

Tags: r

I have a matrix with roughly 160 data points. I am interested in finding out if any part of that series(doesn't have to be the whole series) has a trend (linear and either increasing/decreasing). I am only interested in finding out the linear trend and not nonlinear trends.

I would start by testing it on a basic data set of the form:

```
A < c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,17,18,17,17,18,17,17,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19)
```

Here by just plotting the data, I would think that the trend is upwards from 1:17 and I would want to introduce dummies for that (which I will be able to do once I know the trend start point and endpoint). Is there any way to know that? IN R?

Comment: To find a linear trend you need at least 2 variables. How are we supposed to see a trend in your vector? putting it from 1 to19 will show a increasing trend and putting it from 19 to 1 will show a decreasing trend.

Comment: I am not quite sure as to what you mean by 2 variable. In time series, trend is calculated only on one variable and not two.

Comment: I believe in time series is plotted between time and frequency. See two variables here.

Comment: Yes but they are assumed to be present in a time series format if i do the ts transformation. The function ts assumes that all the values in A are one time period apart.

Answer (score 2):

```
A<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
     16,17,17,18,17,17,18,17,17,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19)
x <- seq_along(A)

plot(A ~ x)

fit0 <- lm(A ~ x)

library(segmented)
fit1 <- segmented(fit0, seg.Z = ~ x, psi = list(x = c(10, 40)))
summary(fit1)
#Estimated Break-Point(s):
#         Est. St.Err
#psi1.x 18.00  0.220
#psi2.x 34.04  0.246


lines(x, predict(fit1), col = "red")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Sir, this is for multiple trends?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `lm` function. This function help you to create a linear regression.

```
A<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,17,18,17,17,18,17,17,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19)
x = c(1:length(A))  
plot(x,A)
reg = lm(A~x)
abline(reg,col="red")
```

[image: Linear regression]

And if you want start your linear regression at a **startPoint**, use `A[**startPoint**:length(A)]

And to know the trend :  `print(reg)`

Comment: But this trend line is for the whole dataset, right?

Comment: I want R to predict if there is a linear trend and if yes then from which point to which point. So that I can add a dummy for the same.

Comment: So look `summary(reg)`. This help you to know if there is a linear trend, or no with the p-value (**Pr(>|t|)**). The value on the x-row need to be <2e-16

Comment: And to know at which point start, you have to do a loop on a startpoint, and create each time a linear regression, and look up if there is a trend or not (with the p-value)

Comment: But then it can show me multiple trends as the null hypothesis can be rejected at multiple points and thereby giving overlapping trends?

Comment: There is two options :
- Classify your dataset in multiple groups (manually or automatically). Then use lm on each group
- Or, create a loop, and stop it when you have a trend.

Answer (score 0):

The decompose function could help. A dummy might not be sensitive enough. You might just want to subtract the trend component. Try:

```
A<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
 16,17,17,18,17,17,18,17,17,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19)

# convert to ts first
my.ts <- ts(A, start = c(2000, 1), freq = 12) # .. if you have months
my.trend <- decompose(my.ts)$trend
print(max(diff(my.trend), na.rm = TRUE))

# use a certain percentage of max difference to find start and end of trend
tolerance <- 0.1 # say 10 % ..
trend.start <- which.max(my.trend >= tolerance * max(my.trend, na.rm=T))
trend.end <- which.max(my.trend >= (1-tolerance) * max(my.trend, na.rm=T))

# plot shows that it - almost - fits
plot(my.ts, col = "blue", type = "o")
abline(v = time(my.ts)[trend.start], col = "gray") 
abline(v = time(my.ts)[trend.end], col = "gray")
lines(my.trend)

# but what do you do, if you have a ts like this ..
B <- c(rep(0,50), seq(1,30,0.5), rep(30,50), seq(30,1,-1)) + rnorm (189,0,1)
my.ts <- ts(B, start = c(2000, 01), freq = 12)
plot(my.ts)
my.trend <- decompose(my.ts)$trend
plot(my.trend)
```

Comment: Sir, this works beautifully but I am not quite sure what all is happening here

Comment: Sir, one question, if I have weekly data, how do I introduce the frequency? I have 3 year's data and weekly. I also have the dates for those data points.

Comment: And in the ts shared by you in the very last part of your answer, I can see that your method detects only an upward trend? Also, you said to use a certain percentage of max difference but you haven't used it and just used max value multiplied by the tolerance level?